# How to extract all user's email id under a workspace domain?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-workspace

I want to extract all employees email id under our company workspace domain and I want to get them without using Admin SDK Api. Somebody please help me

The best way I vape found on the web was to use Admin SDK Api but my company's system admin is not willing to give me the credentials because it is capable of doing more than what I ask for.

Comment: The only way to get that kind of information is to go though the Admin SDK.  Or be an admin of the workspace domain.    If your admin wont give you access this is probably because its not something they want you to have access to.

Comment: Alright thanks for the response man... Appreciate it